# django throwing error "Cannot convert model field category to an Elasticsearch field!"

Tags: django, python-3.x, elasticsearch-5

I'm making my models work with elastic search and I added simple code in documents.py in my app directory but

```
$ ./manage.py search_index --rebuild
```

Gives

> "django_elasticsearch_dsl.exceptions.ModelFieldNotMappedError: Cannot convert model field category to an Elasticsearch field!"

## models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Category(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    slug = models.SlugField( default="cslug")
    picture = models.FileField(upload_to="static/product_pics/")
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='children')

    class Meta :
        ordering = ('name', )
        unique_together = ('slug', 'parent',)
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('store:productlist', args=[])

    def __str__(self):
        full_path = [self.name]
        k=self.parent

        while k is not None:
            full_path.append(k.name)
            k=k.parent

        return '->'.join(full_path[::-1])
```

## documents.py

```py
from django_elasticsearch_dsl import Document
from django_elasticsearch_dsl.registries import registry
from .models import Category, Brand, Product

@registry.register_document
class CategoryDocument(Document):
    class Index:
        name = 'categories'
        settings = {'number_of_shards': 1,
                    'number_of_replicas': 0}

    class Django:
        model = Category

        fields = [
            'name',
        ]
```

Comment: Have you solve this issue ?

I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 2):

https://django-elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html

The problem is the ForeignKey. Elasticsearch is not a relational database, so you have to tell it some way to store your ForeignKey data

try

```py
@registry.register_document
class CategoryDocument(Document):
    parent = fields.ObjectField(properties={
        'name': fields.TextField()
    })

    class Index:
        name = 'categories'
        settings = {'number_of_shards': 1,
                    'number_of_replicas': 0}

    class Django:
        model = Category

        fields = [
            'name',
        ]
        related_models = [Category]
```

Here, the ForeignKey data is stored as a text field.